# How do I fix certificate errors when running wget on an HTTPS URL in Cygwin Windows?

Tags: cygwin, wget

I have Cygwin installed in my windows system.
I am trying to execute `wget` command for a website but I am getting the following error message:

```
ERROR: The certificate of `example.com' is not trusted.
ERROR: The certificate of `example.com' hasn't got a known issuer.
```

How do I fix this issue - so that I can proceed further.

Comment: This is the proper way to fix this issue with cygwin http://stackoverflow.com/a/15252756/799161

Answer (score 9):

If you don't care about checking the validity of the certificate just add the `--no-check-certificate` option on the `wget` command-line.

Edit:

Not checking the validity of the certificate opens you up to man-in-the-middle attacks (MiTM). Depending on the environment you're working in (over the Internet vs. a private LAN) this could be a major vulnerability. Your situation and risk profile should inform your decision.

If you do actually care about checking the validity of the certificate you should provide `wget` with a CA certificate "bundle". Cygwin provides this in the "ca-certificates" package. You can find more specific details [in this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15252756/40764). It looks like there has been little consensus as to the location of the SSL certificate bundle for Cygwin in the past, resulting in the need to specify its location in configuration files or create symlinks to direct applications to the appropriate directory. Your mileage will vary depending on the version of Cygwin tools you're using.

Comment: I tried using -no-check-certificate but it did not help me. 
It is warning and moving forward but wget did not finish my execution
I am trying something like this 

wget --post-data 'email=abc@xxx.com&action=submit&context=SIGNUP' http://www.landsend.com/cgi-bin/newsletter.cgi --no-check-certificate --save-cookies landsend.cookies --keep-session-cookies --load-cookies landsend.cookies

Comment: Hmm... What kind of error message did it terminate with? I'm not sure I want to test that (because I don't really want to POST anything to their web site).

Comment: @EvanAnderson I was having the same issue described in the Question.  Following your suggestion worked well. Thanks!

Comment: with cygwin I have the same problem.

Comment: A better solution is probably to fix the certificate situation in the Cygwin environment. Install new CAs that can validate the SSL certificate of the site you're making requests to.

Comment: @AlexReynolds - MiTM is certainly a serious vulnerability. Getting the right paths in the right places in Cygwin has also been problematic, though, too. Ultimately sysadmins need to be educated about the issue (understanding how trust works in a PKI) and make the right call for their risk profile. Balancing "I just need this to work right now one time" vs. "I need this to be the correct solution" is part of our daily balancing act.